# django - how can I add more to my URL in my views.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a url, http://127.0.0.1:8000/lesson/riff-lab/1305/pentab-wow/

When a user navigates to the above url, I want to change it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/lesson/riff-lab/1305/pentab-wow/?d:a3ugm6eyko59qhr/pentab-Track_1.js

The appended part is needed in order to load something that I want to load, but the specifics are not important for this question.

Here's what I have tried.

```
def my_view(request, pk):
    context = {}
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
    request.GET._mutable = True
    request.GET['?d:%s/%s' % (page.dropbox_key, page.dropbox_js_file_name)] = ""
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Also

```
def my_view(request, pk):
    context = {}
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
    request.GET = request.GET.copy()
    request.GET['?d:%s/%s' % (page.dropbox_key, page.dropbox_js_file_name)] = ""
    return render(request, template, context)
```

These do not change the url.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to change the aim of a shell that already has hit it's target.
URL comes first, then view routed to it is processed, there is no way to change it without making another request, e.g. returning a *redirect response* "please open this url now" to the client.

You can easily find it in django docs by this keywords, **but** what you are trying to do generally doesn't look very reasonable, if you know beforehand how you need to construct url, why change it mid-way or why change it at all if view has all required data? I don't know your context, but it's probable that you need to reconsider your approach.

Comment: I already tried returning a redirect response, and it resulted in an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Add a condition to it, if request.GET has part you need. That should be obvious? If url has ?d:a... - return normal template, if not - redirect to "correct" url.